# How does apache load php files

Tags: php, apache

I am new to PHP web development. Coming from Java/J2EE background, I am trying to understand how apache( Or any webserver ) loads php project files?

In java all classes are loaded in memory by application server. So you could have singletons,global in-memory data structures connection pooling etc.  How does it work in php?

Answer (score 4):

Each time a request to PHP file (after routing done by `mod_rewrite`) in Apache Httpd is made, server essentially startups new equivalent of JVM.

You use - among others - cookies, database and files to persist any data.

> How does it work in php?

Slow